Stripped a door, what's this wood pattern?
We just finished stripping a few layers of paint and varnish off our old wooden dining room door. Both vertical boards reveal this kind of nice leopard pattern (see photo). Is this something cool, like spalded maple, or is it maybe more disappointing, like irregular staining by some past drunken painter?
Extra details: 1600 sq ft house, was built in 1920 (Connecticut) as a multi-generation family home; we are only the second owners. Floors are maple downstairs, woodwork is ALL painted.


My first thought is the pattern is not a natural occurrence, may not be a drunken painter,  but I am sure it is not a "quilted" grain

I think the pattern on the left, if that's what you're asking about, is incomplete stripping rather than anything in the wood. I would suggest sanding it further, or planing it, to get down to unstained wood. (Typo fixed.) Of course if this is a relatively new or inexpensive piece, beware of the possibility that the outer surface is veneer... But that appears unlikely in this photo.

The "alligator skin" pattern looks to me like a previous finish dried out and cracked—like when you see mud dry out in a lake bed.  +1 with keshlam on sanding it down to bare wood—or even below.

Thanks! Yeah, we hadn't started sanding at this point and it is coming off as we do. I kind of liked it though!
